# Load script if screen wide enough AND if parent div is in view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a twitter feed I currently display on my website when the viewport is 1250px or wider. So when the screen is wide enough, it calls in some content (which calls the javaScript file for the twitter feed.

My current code is this...

```
function checkSize(){
    if ($(window).width() > 1250) {
        $(".tweet").load("/ajax/");
    }
}

checkSize();

$(window).resize(function() {
    checkSize();
});
```

Now this works fine, however as the twitter script is near the bottom of the page, how can I  only load the script when the div appears in user view?

I have tried something like this however it does not work

```
function checkSize(){
    if ($(window).width() > 1250 && $(".tweet").is(':visible'))  {
        $(".tweet").load("/ajax/");
    }
}
```

So to confirm, I want to only call in this content when the screen width is 1250px or wider AND when the user is at the bottom of the page so the parent div is visible (.tweet).

Any help would be appreciated.

I have added a codepen to test with here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezksD

Comment: I think you'll have to do some calculations to see if the div is visible in the viewport.  See `.offset()` and `.scrollTop()` to figure out where the div is in the viewport.  You will then have to attach to the scrolling event and recalculate when scrolled if not yet loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to find out how far the user has scrolled to be able to identity if the `div` is visible.
So what you could do is (wrote this from mobile and didn't check your code for syntax errors):

```
var loaded = false;
var proximity = 0;

if (loaded == false){
 $(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollBottom =   $(".tweet").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if (scrollBottom <= proximity && windowWidth > 1250 && loaded == false)
    {
         $(".tweet").load("/ajax/");
         loaded = true;
    }
 });
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: thanks but this does not seem to work on it's own, is there something else I have to do apart from adding it in within a function and then calling that function?

Comment: Don't add it in another function. You don't have to call it. Just copy and paste like it is written here. (You **can** add it to the `$(document).ready(..` function though)

Comment: it still does not seem to work, I have added a codepen to test on http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezksD

Answer (score 0):

This will determine if the user has scrolled down far enough for it to be visible.

```
function checkSize(){
    if ($(window).width() > 1250 && $(".tweet").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop())  {
        $(".tweet").load("/ajax/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work, do I have to add anything else to this?